# jQuery post without a form but with page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, post, http-post

Is it possible to submit POST data to a PHP script using only jQuery, without a form on the page and with page refresh?

**Redirection**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        window.location.replace('index.php?some_value=1');
    });
});
```

In this example GET data is sent, but how can I send POST data with this redirection?

**POST**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $.post(
            'index.php',
            {
                some_value: '1'
            }, function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

This example will not refresh the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the form hidden so as to have the data within a form and then "submit it" yourself.

if you include

```
style="display:none"
```

in your form like this

```
<form style="display:none" action="POST">
    <input field your input field>
    <input maybe another input field>
</form>
```

then you can still submit things via post but not have it show up